# Python: keep game running after converting in py2exe

Tags: python, loops

So I am new to programming and started learning python from a recommendation, I have been combining learning from Learn python the hard way and code academy.

I have made the Pig latin game from code academy and tweaked it slightly so it keeps looping however once I convert it with the help of py2exe to run as an exe in windows it no longer works and I was just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to how to change my script slightly to work.

```
print "Let's do some Pig Latin!"
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

word = original.lower()
first = word[0]
new_word = word + first + pyg


if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print new_word [1:]
    again = raw_input('Would you like to play again? Y/N \n').upper()
else:
    print 'You were supposed to enter a word!,Try again'
    execfile ('pig.py')

if again == 'Y':
    execfile ('pig.py')
else:
    print 'Goodbye!'
```

See it works on the whole fact of just rerunning the script with execfile, but obviously this wouldn't work as a exe file, I have looked at some other questions and answers but because I already had the script kind of working I have confused myself and I just kind of need help understanding how I would restructure the script.

Thanks for any help in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop instead of re-executing the file:

```
should_run = True
print "Let's do some Pig Latin!"
while should_run:
    pyg = 'ay'

    original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word + first + pyg


    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        print new_word [1:]
        again = raw_input('Would you like to play again? [Y/N] \n').upper()
        while again not in "NY":
            again = raw_input("Invalid input. Play again? [Y/N] ").upper()

        should_run = "NY".index(again) # If again is Y, should_run is 1 (True).  Otherwise, it is 0 (False)
    else:
        print 'You were supposed to enter a word!,Try again'
```

Comment: This worked ! thank you for your help
Just so I understand and learn from this, I see two new functions I haven't used before 'Not in' and '.index()'
what is happening with not in? is this feeding back to the while function to make anything in " " is present and if it isn't it runs the while? 
So with that not in I could in theory type "NY1234XLZ" and as if the user typed in any of those the script would carry on but if it was anything outside that range it would carry out the while??

with the .index() I am not quite sure I understand what is happening with that one at all. 
Again Thank you.

Comment: You are correct about `not in`.  Python reads it pretty much how it is read in English.  If `again` is neither `N` nor `Y`, the `while` loop will do another iteration.  For `.index()`, it will return the index of the first occurrence of a string.  If `again` were `Y`, it would return `1` since `"NY"[1]` is `Y`.  `N` would be `0`.  Booleans (`True` and `False`) are really just integers. Zero has a boolean value of `False` and any other number has a boolean value of `True`, so if `again` is `Y`, `should_run` will be `1` or `True`.  If `again` is `N`, `should_run` will be `0` or `False`.